# How to update second textbox automatically with update value using JS

Tags: javascript, php, joomla1.5

I have a PHP Script and two text box. Its kind of currency convert.

If the user want to buy 1 credit which is $5 using the first text box and by hitting tab the next textbox will update automatically by multiplying with a php variable.

Can it possible using simple inline JavaScript ?

My PHP variable is `$currentValue`.

1st Test-box is name & id="credit"
2nd Text-box is name & id="finalRupee"

Please see the below code its in a function.php file

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="userFormJob" onSubmit="return   validateForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width= "100%">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><strong><?php echo JText::_( 'PRICE FOR 1 CREDIT' ); ?> = <?php echo  $currencytype . ' ' . $currency.' '; ?> &nbsp;<?php echo $price_credit; ?> (Please Note:   For One credit value you can post 1 Job for 1 Day)</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p> <b>
<?php 
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?From=USD&To=INR&    Amount=1.&template=pca-xetrade"); 
$content = explode('<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=3 CELLSPACING=0>',$content);
$content = str_replace('<TD VALIGN=MIDDLE ALIGN=RIGHT><FONT     FACE="Arial,Helvetica"><B>', "", "$content[1]");
$content = explode('<TD COLSPAN=3 ALIGN=CENTER><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica"     SIZE=-2>',$content);
$toremove = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", ">", "<", "\"", "\'", "=", ",", "/", "-1");

$content = str_replace($toremove, "", "$content[0]");
$final = explode('+1',$content);

$from_code  = "USD";
$to_code    = "INR";
$currency   = $config-> get('currency');

echo '<b>' .$final[0]. ' ' .$from_code. ' =' .$final[1]. ' ' .$to_code. '</b>';
?>
</b></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo JText::_( 'BUY' ); ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="credit" id="credit" class="inputbox"     onKeyPress="return     isNumberKey(event)" />
<?php 
$currentValue = $final[1];
?>
<?php echo JText::_('CREDIT'); ?>
<input name="finalRupee" type="text" class="inputbox" id="finalRupee" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" value="<?php ?>" readonly /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" >Please Use Currency Convert for Dollar to Rupees <a     href="http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?Amount=1&From=USD&To=INR&template=8n"     target="_blank">Click Here</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" ><b><?php echo JText::_('BILLING ADDRESS'); ?></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo JText::_('ADDRESS'); ?></td>
<td><input class="inputbox" type="text" name="address" id ="address" size="40"     maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $row->bill_addr; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo JText::_('ADDRESS CONT'); ?>:</td>
<td><input class="inputbox" type="text" size="40" maxlength="255" name="address_cont" id ="address_cont" value="<?php echo $row->bill_addr_cont; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo JText::_('CITY'); ?>: </td>
<td><input class="inputbox" type="text" name="city" id ="city" value="<?php echo     $row->bill_city; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo JText::_('STATE'); ?>:</td>
<td><input class="inputbox" type="text" name="state" id ="state" value="<?php echo     $row->bill_state; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo JText::_('COUNTRY'); ?>:</td>
<td><?php 
$list_country = getSelectCountry('id_country',$row->bill_id_country,'');
echo $list_country;
?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo JText::_('ZIP POSTAL'); ?>:</td>
<td><input class="inputbox" type="text" name="zip" id ="zip" value="<?php echo         $row->bill_zip; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo JText::_('PHONE'); ?>:</td>
<td><input class="inputbox" type="text" name="phone" id ="phone" value="<?php echo     $row->bill_phone; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo JText::_('PAYMENT'); ?>:</td>
<td><select name="mode_pay">
<option value="m"><?php echo JText::_('MANUAL'); ?> / <?php echo JText::_('TRANSFER');     ?></option>
<option value="p">PayPall Secure Pay</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><center>
<img src="http://www.jobodisha.com/images/stories/powered_by.png" alt="Pay Pal Secure Payments" width="497" height="149" align="absmiddle">
</center></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo JText::_( 'BUY' ); ?>" class="button" />
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="<?php echo $option; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="savebuycredit" />
<input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
<?php echo JHTML::_('form.token'); ?>
</form>
```

Comment: If either my answer or DeviantSeev's helped, you could select the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need php to do the simple multiplication calculation. Simple inline jquery code for this would be:

```
var individualCost= 5;
var amount = $("#credit").val();
$("#finalRupee").val(amount * individualCost);
```

Comment: This is a joomla site and the file is in a function file of a module and I don't know if it will work? do i need to put your script under <script></script> tag?

Comment: Yes you will need to put it inside the script tag but you might need to do additional things to get it working exactly how you want. Also, you need to make sure that the site has jquery installed otherwise this code won't work and you can use Rhino's plain javascript solution instead.

Comment: @DeviantSeev - Your solution is easier if jQuery is included, and is much simpler to understand, although it would be a little more complex if it had the event handlers included.

Comment: @Rhino - Yeah, got to love jquery for making our lives so easy. I use it so much that I am begining to forget some basic Javascript functions... sad.

Comment: @DeviantSeev - Well, I storta still like good old plain JS.  It just has a lack of abstraction and, frankly, weirdness.  What is CSS doing in an JS selector?  (`$(".class > div")`)  It's a little much for me to accept, but I admit that it would make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

I would get the variable into JavaScript from PHP using

```
<script>var conversionRate = <?php echo $currentValue; ?>;</script>
```

And then process the conversion in JavaScript when the first text box losses focus:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("credit").onblur = function() {
        document.getElementById("finalRupee").value = this.value * conversionRate;
    };
</script>
```

The code works without any add-on libraries.  If you are already using jQuery or another library, you may prefer shorter code, but this works without any dependencies.

Please tell me if there is anything I can elaborate on, or if there is something I didn't answer.

**Update**
Just realized I had put `<?php echo $currentValue; ?>` in quotes, which it shouldn't be.  The code has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below method and its work for me.

```
<?php 

    $content = file_get_contents("http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?From=USD&To=INR&Amount=1.&template=pca-xetrade"); 

    $content = explode('<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=3 CELLSPACING=0>',$content);

    $content = str_replace('<TD VALIGN=MIDDLE ALIGN=RIGHT><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica"><B>', "", "$content[1]");

    $content = explode('<TD COLSPAN=3 ALIGN=CENTER><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" SIZE=-2>',$content);

    $toremove = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", ">", "<", "\"", "\'", "=", ",", "/", "-1");

    $content = str_replace($toremove, "", "$content[0]");

    $final = explode('+1',$content);

    $from_code  = "USD";

    $to_code    = "INR";

    $currency   = $config-> get('currency');

    echo '<h3> Today Cost of ' .$final[0]. ' ' .$from_code. ' =' .$final[1]. ' ' .$to_code. '</h3>';
?>
```